# Ajax working on IE and Safari but no working in FF, Chrome and Opera.

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying to get the data for Modal from a html page via jQuery Ajax, it is working in Safari and even in IE 6 but it is not working in Firefox, Chrome or Opera. Please advice!

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vJx39/).

Comment: I usually see preventDefault() called first in the click function

Answer (score 2):

I see some unusual use of selectors here:

in your code...

`$close = $('<a id="close" href="#">close</a>');`

You've added the click event as:

```
        $close.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            method.close();
        });
```

I truly believe that's not gonna work anyway... the correct option to bind an event would involve a proper jQuery selector like :

```
        $('#close').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            method.close();
        });
```

or the variable `$close` should refer to such a selector like `$close = $('#close');`

Comment: Thanks for tips Vishal, then I tried to change the codes but its not work, modal is not opening. Is there any solution for calling the html page via ajax. It works in all IE version and Safari, not in FF, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: OH, Case closed!  Its all working pretty well when I test it through MAMP :P